# Android : Gridview cuts the edges of the items

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have a problem with my `gridview`, I don't understand why it cuts the edges of the items instead of resizing them so that they could fit . I would like to see all items entirely on every screen size. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks

Here is a XML code I used:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="522dp"
    android:columnWidth="120dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2"></GridView>
```

item layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: looks like this]

Comment: Show yout item layout

Comment: Can you please post your item layout?

Comment: set padding for gridview

Comment: added  the item layout

Comment: I can't see your item layout code.

Comment: Sorry Nitin, my mistake, now you can see it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add **padding** to your CardView layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
      xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
      android:layout_width="100dp" 
      android:layout_height="100dp" 
      android:layout_margin="0dp" 
      android:padding="11dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"> 

        <ImageView 
           android:id="@+id/image" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter" /> 

 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: thx for the idea, adding padding didn't help, I tried it again, but still looks the same  :(